# Как правильно пишутся просторечные сокращения?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишутся просторечные сокращения: "велик" или "велек", "телик" или "телек"? За "телЕк" говорит слово "телЕвидение". Вообще, мне попадаются оба варианта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Велик". Тут сомнений быть не может.
А вот насчет "телика" - "телека"... Спор бесконечный. На моей памяти в разных местах было как минимум три дискуссии. Ещё, помнится, этим уродцем "теликом" очень возмущался Андрей Вознесенский. Но приходится, следуя словарям, писать "телик", хотя это образование из разряда "паралимпиады", "каратиста", "рекетёра" и прочего, когда в угоду непонятно каким принципам жертвуется морфологическая правильность параолимпиады, каратэиста и рекетира. В последнем случае, правда, удалось частично отстоять законность рекетира, может и такой родной "телек" не падёт жертвой борьбы за икающий суффикс.

(+) 
Дополню из своего же комментария.
"Телек" мотивируется предположением, что "теле" здесь корень. Очень, конечно, необычно такое образования с помощью изолированного суффикса "К", но ведь и сами подобные новоделы не подчиняются каким-то правилам. Ср. "видак",  "писюк", "мобила" - какие угодно суффиксы.

Кстати, интересно, что модв на подобные сокращения проходит. Так, смартофон, планшет и скутер (которым теперь величают мотороллер)  пока что не удостоились чести иметь никнейм.

Answer (score 0):

Словари дают вариант "велик". Я считаю, что это правильно. Ведь слово образовано от слова "велосипед": вел - часть основы, ик - очень похоже на суффикс, как и в других словах: зайчик, винтик; велик- велика - гласная не выпадает, значит, это И. Аналогично - телик.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно приведённому в дискуссии по адресу http://lingvoforum.net/index.php/topic,67586.msg2079927.html#msg2079927

> Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный 
>   академический справочник / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина. — 
>   М: Эксмо, 2007. - 480 с.
>
> > § 50. -ек, -ик. Следует различать  уменьшительно-ласкательные суффиксы существительных мужского рода -ек (в  безударной позиции) и -ик, -чик (всегда безударные). В суффиксе -ек гласный (проверяемый под ударением в словах типа пенёк, творожок) является беглым, а в суффиксах -ик и -чик гласный при склонении сохраняется. Таким образом, беглый гласный передается здесь буквой е (см. § 64), а небеглый — буквой и, напр.: овражек — овражка, кусочек — кусочка, ножичек —  ножичка, барашек — барашка, но столик — столика, калачик — калачика, стаканчик — стаканчика. 
> >     По этому же правилу пишутся характерные для  разговорной речи и просторечия образования на -ик с небеглым  гласным суффикса и усеченной основой производящего слова типа велик (велосипед), телик (телевизор), видик  (видеомагнитофон), шизик (шизофреник), а также усеченные  уменьшительные личные имена типа Алик, Владик.

Comment: К сожалению, это не более чем дискуссия, каковых много. Девять человек имеют десять попарно взаимоисключающих мнений. Вопрос в том, есть ли в слове "телек" этот самый суффикс, или "теле" здесь корень. Почитав по этому поводу достаточно много, склоняюсь именно к последнему варианту.